# AttributeError when using lettuce 'world'

Tags: lettuce

I have two files:

steps.py:

```
from lettuce import *
from splinter.browser import Browser

@before.harvest
def set_browser():
  world.browser = Browser('webdriver.chrome')
@step(u'Given I visit "([^"]*)"')
def given_i_visit(step, url):
  world.browser.visit(url)
```

test.feature:

```
Feature: Do some basic tests
  Scenario: Check whether the website is accessable
    Given I visit "/"
```

Running lettuce against them returns this:

```
Feature: Do some basic tests                        # features/test.feature:1

  Scenario: Check whether the website is accessable # features/test.feature:2
  Given I visit "/"                               # features/steps.py:8
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/..../site-packages/lettuce/core.py", line 125, in __call__
      ret = self.function(self.step, *args, **kw)
    File "/..../test/features/steps.py", line 9, in given_i_visit
      world.browser.visit(url)
  AttributeError: 'thread._local' object has no attribute 'browser'

1 feature (0 passed)
1 scenario (0 passed)
1 step (1 failed, 0 passed)
```

Any ideas on what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Although not in the documentation. place the terrain.py file in the same directory as your steps and features files. Initialized the world attribute with any value and you should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the before.harvest takes some data, so the right code will be the following:

```
from lettuce import *
from splinter import Browser

@before.harvest
def set_browser(data):
  world.browser = Browser('webdriver.chrome')

@step(u'Given I visit "([^"]*)"')
 def given_i_visit(step, url):
  world.browser.visit(url)
```

hope it helps!